# Netbeans 7.3 - new html5 project - where to place php and mvc?

Tags: client-side, server-side, netbeans-7, restful-architecture

I may perhaps been missing something really basic here.

Netbeans 7.3 just came up, with this new HTML5 project feature.

It seems interesting, but the way it's setup make me ask some questions that tremble the foundations of our own way of developing.

1) If we build using MVC structure on a given php framework, how can we then relate those with the HTML5 project feature ?

2) As far as web development concerns, I'm taking into consideration that there's no such think as a useful HTML5 application without the server side counterpart (login, database etc...). - Am I wrong ?

3) Until now, we have developing on the same project both Server Side, and Client Side, using MVC to order those different programming approaches. However, this seems to force us to split the development of the client side as one separate project and the server side of things as another project.
Regarding this point 3, are very big projects done with this separation ?

Any lights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML and JS editor improvements are available in PHP projects as well. If you'd like to use other HTML5 specific features then yes you need to split your project into server-side and client-side part. In many cases you could actually benefit from that, as it will force you to remove unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: @Mchl - At some point however, we should glue those ends. What methods exist actually to "glue" both sides on that scenario?

Comment: Build tools like Maven. Also note, that you can infact configure PHP project in the same directory as HTML5 project, although I'm pretty sure this approach can lead to some unexpected quirks.

Comment: Netbeans plan to integrate this later on. Don't have the source with me atm. But they do plan to integrate it with other types of projects.